# What is "chain identifier" in PDB?

Tags: pdb

The PDB file format is explained [here](http://deposit.rcsb.org/adit/docs/pdb_atom_format.html). My question is what "chain identifier" is exactly? What is the difference between two residues which have the same sequence number but different chain identifiers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "chain identifier" does exactly what it says: it identifies the polypeptide or other molecular chain. For some structures, there is only one, so you'll only see an identifier `A`. However, many structures show two or more proteins bound together, or an enzyme complexed to a substrate, or a small molecule inhibitor in a binding pocket - there are many different possibilities. Each individual chain of atoms has its own identifier.

For example, [1VKX](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=1VKX) shows my favorite transcription factor NF-κB bound to the κB DNA enhancer sequence. There are four chains in the structure: two polypeptide chains, the p65 subunit `A` and the p50 subunit `B`, and two DNA chains `C` and `D`, one for each strand (forward and reverse).

[image: 1VKX]